# Show JOptionPane Message with any exception

Tags: java, exception, joptionpane

I want to run my program in a Runnable Jar file but the problem is that sometimes I got errors and it display in the eclipse console, is there anyway I can display all runtime errors (exceptions) in a JOptionPane Message so I could know that my program is doing wrong withouts the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [global exception handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) for UI thread.